# MYSQL- Unable to calculate timediff between to fields and unable to use where clause

Tags: mysql

This is the SQL query to calculate the time difference between DateTimeSolved and DateTimeCreated and i need the result to be in hours.

```
$query = "SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved TIMEDIFF(HOUR, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
From problem";
```

I have added in a where clause into my query:

$query = "SELECT problem.status, problem.id, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
From problem
WHERE problem.status = '5'
GROUP BY MONTH(problem.DateTimeCreated) = MONTH(CURDATE())";                                                                                       This is the current format of the query it works but the output i get is a negative.

I am still getting this error when I try to run the statement:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>
> check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: Format your queries more clearly. Then the problem will obvious.

Comment: $query = "SELECT problem.status, problem.id, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
From problem
WHERE problem.status = '5'
GROUP BY MONTH(problem.DateTimeCreated) = MONTH(CURDATE())";                                                                                       This is the current format of the query it works but the output i get is a negative.

Comment: You have no aggregating functions, so it's non-sensical to GROUP BY anything.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma and the timediff functions requires only two values, to format it (present only the hour) use the following query:

```
SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved, TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated), '%k %i')
From problem
```

Comment: i added in the comma but i get another error.  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'

Comment: remove the hour from the timediff function, see my updated post

Comment: for formatting use the time_format or date_format functions of mysql

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to missing a comma before the TIMEDIFF function:

```
SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved, TIMEDIFF(HOUR, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
```

From problem

Then you will find that your parameters for TIMEDIFF are incorrect. This should work:

```
SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved, TIMEDIFF( problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
From problem
```

If you need just the hours:

```
SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved, HOUR(TIMEDIFF( problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)) From problem
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT problem.id, problem.DateTimeCreated, problem.DateTimeSolved TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, problem.DateTimeSolved, problem.DateTimeCreated)
From problem";
```